# Issue with Dynamic Memory Allocation for a char Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, dynamic-programming, dynamic-memory-allocation

Im trying to write a program in c that allocates memory for a 'char' array with dimension of n,m. Below is what i tried but every time i run it, no matter what dimensions i give it returns a value of -2 without even printing "Error in memory allocation.".
What do you guys think?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){
    int i,j,n,m;
    char **p;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);         //get array dimensions
    p=malloc(n*sizeof(char *));
    if (p==NULL){
        printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        p[i]=malloc(m*sizeof(char));
        if (p[i]==NULL)
            printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
            return -2;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Typo. You're missing `{}` after the last `if`, so `return -2` is always executed the first time around the loop.

Comment: very true, edited. thanks im a dummy

Comment: You want to learn to use a debugger to trace code step by step. This often enlightens you what is really going on.

Comment: Now your code doesn't compile. Fix your code on your machine and run it again.

Comment: Do not change you question after answers had been given, as this might render answers ununderstandable. I rolled back your edit therefore. Update your question by adding stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    if (p[i]==NULL)
        printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
        return -2;
```

must be

```
    if (p[i]==NULL) {
        printf("Error in memory allocation.\n");
        return -2;
    }
```

Some coding guides require to always put `{}` with if statements (even with a single statement) to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: thanks man, now i feel silly